# File size and encoding

Tags: windows, unicode

I created a text file in notepad in windows saved it with Unicode encoding. the file was completely blank and is saved as 0 byte size as expected.

I saved it again (still empty text file) as utf - 8 encoding and it saved with a size of 3 bytes.

Can anyone explain where the 3 bytes came from.

cheers

Comment: Possibly [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: I didn't know what that was. I followed your link back and it seems very plausible. Thank you

Comment: Note: "Unicode" is not an encoding. There are many Unicode encoding. Microsoft show again incompetence (in order to simplify to users, it will confuse them). My options in notepad: "ANSI" (which is wrong, ANSI is ASCII, or eventually Latin1 [so without some characters that windows uses]), "Unicode" (what??), "Unicode big endian" (starting to get crazy), and "UTF-8" (finally an encoding).

Comment: Microsoft uses the terms *Unicode* and *UTF-16 LE* interchangeably, due to historic reasons. Back when work on Windows NT started, Microsoft decided to use Unicode internally. A blunt move, considering that it was 1989. They 'chose' UCS-2, because UCS-2 was all there was at the time. NT was updated to support UTF-16 with the release of Windows 2000. Still, *Unicode* meant one thing only: *UTF-16 LE*. To disambiguate any ambiguities, Notepad now offers the following options for saving files: *"ANSI"*, *"UTF-16 LE"*, *"UTF-16 BE"*, *"UTF-8"*, and *"UTF-8 with BOM"*.

Answer (score 0):

The description of what you are doing is incorrect. Saving an empty file in Notepad using the *"UTF-8"* encoding produces a file with size 0. Notepad, however, also allows you to save files as *"UTF-8 with BOM"* ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)). The BOM identifying text as UTF-8 is the sequence of bytes `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`. This explains, why an otherwise empty file stored as UTF-8 with BOM is 3 bytes in size.

Comment: Note: On my Notepad, I doesn't have "UTF-8 with BOM", but I have "Unicode" and "UTF-8".